# how to get currently running threads

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor to launch the threads which process requests from a blocking queue. In case of queue is empty, all these worker threads are waiting. which makes every thread in this pool is on Wait state.

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                EngineConfiguration.numberOfSearchTask,
                EngineConfiguration.numberOfSearchTask + 10, 1000,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, worksQueue, executionHandler);
```

I have also launched below scheduled executore  which tries to get current active threads in the above pool and when it is 0 then it shutdown the pool:

```
final ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleFuture = scheduler
.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int activeThreadCount =   executor.getActiveThreads();
        if (activeThreadCount == 0) { 

SearchTaskRunner.keepRunning.set(false);
                log.warn("shutdown task runner");

            executor.shutdown();

            log.warn("shutdown scheduler");
            scheduler.shutdownNow();




        }
    }
}, 10, 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The problem is that after 10 seconds, the scheduler thread gets activeThreadCount=0 and hence shutdown the pools.

we know that:

> getActiveCount():Returns the approximate number of threads that are
>   actively executing tasks.

This might not give the accurate number of threads are in active state.

is there anyway I get to know if all my threads from first pool are in wait state?

Comment: luckily I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572865/number-of-active-tasks-using-threadpoolexecutor which describes nice logic. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

Comment: It returns all the threads(=8) in the process: `Running Thread: {Thread[main,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1f0dc656, Thread[Thread-1,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@41584807, Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@ae0e515, Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@32, Thread[Finalizer,8,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@29, Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7c, Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1, Thread[Keep-Alive-Timer,8,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@12}`

Comment: luckily I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572865/number-of-active-tasks-using-threadpoolexecutor which describes nice logic. it solved my problem.   Thanks PSR for being the first help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get all running threads and convert set into array

```
Set<Thread> tSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
Thread[] tArray = tSet.toArray(new Thread[tSet.size()]);
```