# How to get number of current running and queued threads from ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I need to get number of running threads in a ThreadPoolExecutor, as well as the Queue size.

I have a working implementation as (keep track of each futures in an arraylist and count which is not completed):

```
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> threadpoolQueue = 
    new java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);

ThreadPoolExecutor threadpool = new java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 
    executingThreads, retryInterval, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, threadpoolQueue);

ArrayList<Future> threads = new ArrayList<Future>();

threads.add(threadpool.submit(/*Runnable*/));

//Get Sizes
int threadpoolRunningThreads = 0;
for (Future obj : threads) {
    if (!obj.isDone()) {
         threadpoolRunningThreads++;
    }
}
logger.debug("Merging all threads threadpool.size=" + threadpoolRunningThreads 
    + ",threadpool.queue.size="+ threadpoolQueue.size());
```

This is a very awkward way of tracking threadpool, and I don't see any methods provided in threadpool that allows to get the number for running and queued threads. I wanna do something like:

```
threadpool.getIncompletedTaskSize();
threadpool.getQueuedTaskSize();
```

Can I achieve this? or at least something easier than my implementation? I am using **Java 1.6**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572865/number-of-active-tasks-using-threadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount()` and `ThreadPoolExecutor#getQueue()#size()` ?

Comment: The source code for getQueue() returns the original queue, so your `threadpoolQueue.getSize()` should work exactly the same as `ThreadPoolExecutor#getQueue()#size()`. For active count, Java 7 counts the number of internal workers that is locked (i.e. executing). Your method of counting unfinished futures should be good if as long as your `executingThreads ` is larger than 10.

Comment: yep you can see above - also it may be better to upgrade to Java 8? But I guess you may not have control on that?

Comment: My stupidity. I declared it as an `ExecutorService`.